# How to revoke Users Access On Schema in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-schema

I have a requirement where I need to revoke users access on a particular schema as we will be purging that schema and its table in future.

Currently, the process followed to create Schema and grant access is like below,

1. Create Schema
2. Create DB Role
3. Create Azure AD Group on azure portal
4. Create DB User with the same name as AD group
5. Then, we run EXEC sp_addrolemember command to add DB user to DB role in database.
6. Finally, we run the Grant command to give permission (Select, Insert etc) on Schema to DB Role.

Now, whenever any new user need access to that schema we simply add him in the Azure AD group and he is able to see and access that schema.

However, when I Revoke the access of user by removing him from Azure AD group he is still able to see that Schema.

As I am not an expert in SQL so I am not sure what am I missing in order to revoke his access.

I also tried Revoke command like below but still the user is able to see the schema.

REVOKE SELECT ON SCHEMA :: Schema_Name TO [DB Role]

Am I missing anything, can anyone please let me know the right steps to revoke user access so that they should not be able to see that schema anymore or should not be able to run any command on that schema not even select command?

Comment: What do you mean by "see" the schema? Being able to see objects in the *database* does not mean you have access to those objects.

Comment: I meant, It should not be visible itself if possible to those users whose access is revoked on that schema but if its not how it works then the other approach is fine.

Comment: No, that isn't how permissions work. The fact you can *see* an object does not denote you have access to it. The permission to see objects in a database, for example, is a database permission, not a schema permission. I have no doubt that if you authenticated as the `USER` in question and tried to `SELECT` from an object on the schema, you would get a permission denied error.

Comment: Somehow, Its not giving any error which it should when running the SELECT command, its displaying the result. I have removed the user from AD group and that's the reason I not sure what else am I missing.

Comment: This means that they have been `GRANT`ed the `SELECT` permission by something else. Either an explicit permission the `USER` has, or a role that they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Then, in addition to remove it from the AD group, try to deny permissions on the schema:

```
DENY SELECT,VIEW DEFINITION On SCHEMA::Schema_Name To [user_name]
```